# graph description

Tags: prepositions

Originally, the information is presented graphically in a pie chart, but here for simplicity, the part in question is verbalized.

> In 2003
>   Travel sector 36%
>   Clothing sector 24%
>
> In 2013
>   Travel sector 29%
>   Clothing sector 16%

The description sentences as follow:

> In 2003, the online sales in the travel sector accounted for 36% of total retail sales, which was 12% higher than sales in the clothing sector. The online sales in the travel sector and in the clothing sector declined ***by*** the year 2013, with 29% and 16% respectively of total sales by sector.

My question is about the appropriateness of the preposition of "by." The given information is about only two years, and whether there was a rise or not between them is unknown. It seems to me that "declined by" means a continuous drop without any rise. Please enlighten me.

Comment: As a learner: by the year 2013 is a adverbial prepositional phrase modifying the verb "decline". It just says by that time the sales dropped. I don't think it gives any other additional info about the ups and downs involved.

Comment: `here for simplicity, the part in question is verbalized` - not really appropriate for _written_ use.

Comment: online sales in the travel sector. No the. Generally, statistics say X declined IN some year.

Answer (score 1):

*By* indicates when something happens, with little precision. In your example it means *around the year 2013*.

For locations, *by* means [*near or next to*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/by#Preposition), it's the same meaning for referring to time instead of space.

---

For a future date it can also means *at some unspecified time before*:

> The company vowed to ban all plastic containers **by** 2022.

> Renewables can reduce CO2 emissions by 70% **by** 2050